# How can I delete workflow rules using the Migration Tool?

Tags: workflow, migration-tool

I'm trying to delete **all** of the worflow rules & triggered tasks associated with a custom object, using the Force.com Migration Tool, but I keep getting errors.

First I tried to submit blank workflow metadata use the following `destructiveChanges.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Custom_Object__c</members>
    <name>Workflow</name>
  </types>
  <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

...but I get this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\...\build.xml:69: FAILURES:
Error: workflows/Custom_Object__c.workflow(Custom_Object__c):Cannot delete a workflow 
object; Workflow Rules and Actions must be deleted individually
```

But when I tried to list the indivual rules and actions in the `<members>` lists, I got an error that those workflow components couldn't be found.

**How can I delete these?**  I'm trying to avoid having to go into each workflow rule, deactivate it, then deleting the field updates, and finally deleting the workflow rules.

Comment: Have you tried using the WorkflowRule component type, i believe the member name would Custom_Object__c.MyRule. There is also a WorkflowTask component type.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Workflow Rules have their own component type, as do Workflow Tasks, try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
  <types>
    <members>Custom_Object__c.MyRule</members>
    <name>WorkflowRule</name>
  </types>
  <version>26.0</version>
</Package>
```

You may have to do this for WorkflowTask's as well.

**Follow up question via comment below...**

The WorkflowRule and WorkflowTask appear in the package folder structure as follows. They basically use the /workflows folder and the .workflow file extension. You can read more about them in the Metadata API developers guide [here](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_workflow.htm).

[image]

[image]

P.S. If your interested in the above code it is [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi).

Comment: What folder of my deployment directory would I put the relevant files (if it were a deployment -- source code obviously not needed for destructive changes)

Comment: I've updated my answer to clarify this.

Comment: Got it, so it works similarly to custom fields, which can be listed discretely but are still included in the same metadata object.  Really helpful, thanks!