# DestructiveChanges.xml fails because component doesn't exist

Tags: ant, destructivechanges.xml

I'm attempting to deploy a destructiveChanges.xml file. When I include

```
<types>
    <members>Populate_Unit_Price</members>
    <members>Line_Item_Updated</members>
    <name>WorkflowRule</name>
</types>
```

The deployment fails and I receive an error stating it can't find those workflows, but when I remove the those lines the deployment completes successfully. I've also attempted with dot-notation; (i.e. `<members>Line_Item__c.Line_Item_Updated</member>`).

My understanding is that when using [destructiveChanges.xml](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/daas/Content/daas_destructive_changes.htm):

> If you try to delete components that do not exist in the organization, the rest of the deletions will be attempted.

Why would the destructiveChanges deployment fail if it didn't find a component to delete? I even included `rollbackOnError="False"` in the target of the build.xml.

Error Message:

```
All Component Failures:
1.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No ApprovalProcess named: Line_Item__c.Approve_Unit_Price_Change found
2.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No WorkflowRule named: Line_Item_Updatedfound
3.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No WorkflowFieldUpdate named: Line_Item__c.Reset_Price found
4.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No WorkflowFieldUpdate named: Line_Item__c.Copy_Unit_Price found
5.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No WorkflowFieldUpdate named: Line_Item__c.Update_Stock_Inventory found
6.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No ValidationRule named: Line_Item__c.Validate_Quantity found
7.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Line_Item__c.Unit_Price__c found
8.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Line_Item__c.Invoice__c found
9.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Line_Item__c.Quantity__c found
10.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Merchandise__c.Price__c found
11.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Invoice__c.Invoice_Total_del__c found
12.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Invoice__c.Status_del__c found
13.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Merchandise__c.Quantity__c found
14.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Line_Item__c.Line_Item_Total__c found
15.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomField named: Line_Item__c.Merchandise__c found
16.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomObject named: Invoice__c found
17.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomObject named: Merchandise__c found
18.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No CustomObject named: Line_Item__c found
19.  destructiveChanges.xml -- Warning: No WorkflowRule named: Populate_Unit_Price found
*********** DEPLOYMENT FAILED ***********
Total time: 11 seconds
```

I've already successfully deployed the destructiveChange by manually deleting the WFRs in the original question, then deploying the file. All of these errors are components that are already deleted and no longer on the server.

Including my target as well:

```
<target name="DelVFPack">
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.undeploy1}" password="${sf.pwdeploy1}" serverurl="${sf.urldeploy1}" maxPoll="${sf.maxPoll}" deployRoot="src" purgeOnDelete="true" rollbackOnError="False"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Can you add the error message that you are getting? WorkflowRule is not a [metadata type](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_types_list.htm) that I have seen before so it could be complaining about that.

Comment: Thanks @BarCotter, I've added the error message. The WorkflowRule metadata type is found [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_workflow.htm#WorkflowRule). I found that's the correct type via this [StackExchange questions](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4776/how-can-i-delete-workflow-rules-using-the-migration-tool).

Comment: They are all warnings and not errors. Are you sure that the deployment is failing?

Comment: Yup - sorry again, edited to include the deployment failure.

Comment: I'm not going to close this out in case it happens to anyone else, but it appears to be a one time issue. I've tried a Destructive Change deployment with components I knew weren't in the environment and it worked successfully, so it's possible there was an error somewhere on my side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the `ignoreWarnings` attribute to `true` to prevent `sf.deploy` from failing when components in `destructiveChanges.xml` are not found, e.g.

```
  <sf:deploy username="${sf.undeploy1}" ... ignoreWarnings="true" />
```

Comment: Thanks @xn., Unfortunately I can't confirm if this works for me as I don't have the destructive change file anymore. That said it seems like it would be a plausible answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SFDX, then add the `--ignorewarnings` parameter (or `-g`):

```
sfdx force:mdapi:deploy -d destructiveChangesDir -u test -l RunSpecifiedTests -r SomeTestClass --ignorewarnings --wait -1
```

It will then not fail the deploy if there is some non-existing metadata listed in your `destructiveChanges.xml`